# Is there a way to do a lot of computational work effectively in an Android app?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

While building a To-do List app, I wanted to show users the statistics. To-do lists created by users are stored in the Room Database. In order to show statistics on how hard the user has achieved to-do, the number of to-do completions is calculated over the years, but the app is starting to stumble. Even the calculation process is using CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default). I feel that the app is slowing down because I use code like the following to calculate the values ​​in the array.

```
runBlocking {
    withContext(CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default).coroutineContext) {
        var total = 0

        val todoDao = MyDatabase.getInstance(mContext).getTodoDao()
        val todos = todoDao.getTodos()

        for (i in todos) {
            if (i.user_done) {
                total++
            }
        }
    }
}

findViewById(R.id.total).text = total.toString()
```

The code above is part of the statistic calculation process presented to the user. How can you do a lot of calculations more efficiently, for example, when the app is turned on, pre-calculating and re-calculating according to the user's actions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't use Kotlin very much but runBlocking is a sure fire way to slow down the app if its blocking the main thread.
If this is the case, Room has an option to force it to stay off the UI Thread, thus if something is ran on the UI thread it will throw an exception.

The other issue could be memory how big is val todos?
if todos is a large amount of objects then you have them all in RAM(which can get out of hand fast). If so consider batching, by pulling a limited amount and offsetting to pull the next limit, thus you only and have limit amount of objects at any given time, and GC won't hate you.

(edit)
I hate to add a library to the answer but looking into RxJava for Kotlin could be a real game changer, when it comes to these issues, it has worked wonders for me.

Comment: The reason I used ```runBlocking``` was to prevent putting values ​​into text before the calculations are finished. Since I'm not actually using ```runBlocking```, the text didn't get the correct value before it was even calculated. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: If the text is getting updated before the calculations are done then the text update needs to be apart of the result at the end of the coroutine not outside of it. Thus when its actually done the last thing it will do is update the text, meaning you don't have to runBlocking.

Answer (score 2):

You may use the `query` rather than use `for-loop` to do the calculation.
I am not sure your To-Do table schema. However if there is a column for time, you may use this time column as filter to calculate your statistics.

```
SELECT * FROM todo WHERE user_done = TRUE AND timestamp BETWEEN :dayst AND :dayet
```

Using query to do the calculation can make your statistics be more scalable too. I hope you find this information helpful.